# How to access vmware's virtual machine from host windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I am using Ubuntu Server as virtual machine using VMWare inside Windows 7 as host. I can access Windows 7 folders from Ubuntu machine through sharing settings. I'm developing a website on localhost in Ubuntu which i access at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` (using Ubuntu's browser) but when i put the same address into Windows 7's browser, it doesn't loads the website.

How can i access (localhost ) websites which are being accessed inside Ubuntu machine's browser.

What settings to look for? Please Suggest.

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu server in terminal type `ifconfig`to see IP address of that server, you should get output like:

```
# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ... 
          inet addr:192.168.100.106  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5720413 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6295478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

In this example IP is `192.168.100.106`.
So in browser type `http://192.168.100.106:5000/`

Comment: Tried accessing the website into Host Windows 7's browser using the mehtod you told after obtaining ip address from virtual Ubuntu Machine. But still it dind't load.

Comment: Do you have website stored in some subfolder like `http://192.168.100.106:5000/test`. Did you set Apache server on Ubuntu server to listen on 5000 port by yourself or some third party software?

Comment: Its a flask python based website stored in /home/<username>/flasksite folder and its not running on apache... Flask has inbuilt server to serve the site.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and found an answer on Stack: [Flask - configure dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/flask-configure-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network).
You just need to override default host value, when running flask app:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Check [Quick Start](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) guide.